# How to calculate "Outersections" from Sets of date range

Tags: algorithm, date-range, set-theory

Consider a list of sets of date ranges:

[image]

```
A: [{2017/01/01, 2017/01/30},{2017/02/15, 2017/03/05},{2017/03/25, 2017/04/30}]

B: [{2017/01/01, 2017/01/30}]

C: [{2017/01/01, 2017/01/20},{2017/02/19, 2017/03/15}]
```

Is there a efficient way to calculate the "Outersection" intervals (Hatched area, with no intersections between the A,B,C date ranges)?

**EDIT:** @kaidul-islam, thanks for your answer!
I simplified the logic into one `for` and one `if`:

```
...
for (i; i < n - 1; i++) {
    var current := ranges[i];
    var next := ranges[i + 1];

    if (next.left > current.right) {
        gap := next.left - right
        if(gap > 0){
            result.add(gap)
        }
    }
}
```

i missed something?

PS: ranges is sorted by left and right date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort all the set of ranges (`A`, `B` and `C` together) according to ascending order of left date (range with smaller date at left position will come first).

And then follow this pseudo-code:

```
result = []
left := range[0].left
right := range[0].right
i := 0
while(i < n):

   while(i + 1 < n && ranges[i + 1].left <= right):
       right := max(ranges[i + 1].right, right)
       i := i + 1
   end

   if(i + 1 < n):
       gap := ranges[i + 1].left - right
       if(gap > 0):
           result.add(gap)
       endif
   endif

end

return result
```

Time complexity is `O(nlogn)` for sorting and `O(n)` for left to right scan where `n` is the total number of ranges summing up all sets.

Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Hi @kaidul-islam

Comment: Hi @kaidul-islam, thanks for your answer!
I worked on the logic, and i got this:
...
for (i; i < n - 1; i++) {
 var current := ranges[i];
 var next := ranges[i + 1];

 if (next.left > current.right) {
  gap := next.left - right
  if(gap > 0){
   result.add(gap)
  }
 }
}

i missed something?

Comment: Hi @DaniloSampaio You're welcome. I really don't know javascript and this question only asked for the algorithm. Please accept the answer and open a new question with your tried code, put the link and I will try to answer. Thanks!